# Pandas grouping multiple columns with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

When having a simple 2D-DataFrame it is simple to group multiple columns with `df.groupby(["x", "y"])`. However I have a DataFrame with MultiIndices as both index and columns:

```py
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[*["coords"]*3, *["type"]*3],[ "x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c"]])
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[*["values"]*6, "meta"], [*range(6), "foo"]])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,6,7,3], [1,1,0,1,5,9], [2,1,0,1,8,3], [2,1,0,5,7,2], [3,1,0,6,5,9], [3,1,0,7,4,5], [None, None, None, "bar", "baz", "qux"]], index=idx, columns=cols)


           coords           type          
                x    y    z    a    b    c
values 0      1.0  1.0  1.0    6    7    3
       1      1.0  1.0  0.0    1    5    9
       2      2.0  1.0  0.0    1    8    3
       3      2.0  1.0  0.0    5    7    2
       4      3.0  1.0  0.0    6    5    9
       5      3.0  1.0  0.0    7    4    5
meta   foo    NaN  NaN  NaN  bar  baz  qux
```

Now I want to group on the coordinates `["x", "y"]` (`"z"` doesn't matter in this case and could be discarded). I've tried different things such as `df.groupby(["x", "y"])`, `df.groupby(["x", "y"], level=1)`, or `df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level=1, axis=1), "x", "y"])`, however none work. What would be the correct call to achieve a result like (achieved with `.sum()`):

```py
    coords        type          
         x    y      a    b    c
0      1.0  1.0      7   12   12
1      2.0  1.0      6   15    5
2      3.0  1.0     13    9   14
```

Whether the `("meta", "foo")` row is included or not doesn't matter to me, it should be easy enough to add or remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide the "full" column names:

```
>>> df.groupby([("coords","x"),("coords","y")]).sum()

                        coords type        
                             z    a   b   c
(coords, x) (coords, y)                    
1.0         1.0            1.0    7  12  12
2.0         1.0            0.0    6  15   5
3.0         1.0            0.0   13   9  14
```